# Chromium: freeze state

Tags: chromium

When chromium is running, is it possible to freeze the state of the webbrowser (or a single page) and load it back?

My use case is that I want to run a JavaScript snippet on a webpage many times. Rather than loading the page many times, waiting a few seconds for the content and page JavaScript to render, and then run a snippet, I'd like to do the page rendering, save the state, and then run each JS snippet on the same saved state of the rendered page.

EDIT: an acceptable answer includes using the Chromium API or running a custom chromium.

Comment: You can save the html source code, but I don't think you can freeze the state as you mentioned